# I cant find the class name of the discord text messaging box for my python selenium program, what shall I use?

Tags: python, selenium, discord

I am trying to send a message from my account to a discord channel through using a python program.
I tried pyautoGUI's typewrite, but it only works when the window is open. I am thinking of using selenium's `find_element_by_class_name` although I cannot find the class name of the text box.
Can you please guide me through what i can use instead, or another way of sending a message without having to keep the discord window open? I am a newbie so i do not understand complex codes!

Comment: seems like discord has an API (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) that would be easier and more reliable than trying to program against the web ui

Comment: i dont want to use a discrord bot, i want to use my own account